# Is there Any Reason to Promote an InfoPath Field that is not part of a Document Library's Columns?

Tags: document-library, infopath

Had an issue dropped in my lap where an InfoPath form can not be published to library because it is exceeding the max length of 8000. This is an existing published form that has been being used for a few years. So it has been previously published. Upon inspection there are a lot of fields in the InfoPath form being published that are not in the Document Library's Column List.

As the title suggest is there any reason to be promoting InfoPath fields that are not in the Document Library's column list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends. 
1. If you modified the default form of document library or a list you need to promote all the fields that you use in the form. That is simply because IP has not place to safe that data so next time you open the item you will not have it.

2.If you are using **InfoPath Forms library** (not document library) it is not necessary to promote all IP fields only those you will use for reporting or view filters so there is no need to open the xml file IP is using to save the data in Forms Library

I think you are in case 2.

Comment: Thank you Marek, would only those you will use for... also include WorkFlows?

Comment: Workflow field is added when you add the workflow to library and has nothing to do with Infopath itself (unless you have some field WF in IP you created) WF field is required by wf to run correctly. But you might have some old WF in same library not used. TO get rid of those fields I think you need to delete wf before.

Comment: @rezlab's point is that any document library field could be used by a workflow (i.e. read, used in a calculation, etc.). But if you have promoted fields that don't exist in the library right now, then any workflow that is trying to use them is already not working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your talking about a library and not a list, the short answer is no, there is no reason to promote InfoPath fields that are not present in the document library.

The long answer is that logically this shouldn't even be possible to have promoted fields that arn't present in the library since the purpose of promoting fields is to sych data between the form and the library.

Unfortunately, it is very easily possible, because once a form has been published, changes to it's promoted fields will not be pushed to the existing content type in SharePoint. So to get them in SharePoint, you need to delete any form libraries using the content type, the content type itself, and any site columns from promoted fields. Then republish the form.

This is hardly practical in a production library since before you can do that you'd need to delete all of your data.

But if your users have been getting by without this data in SharePoint all this time, the fields never should have been promoted in the first place. Unfortunately, people tend to promote everything instead of giving some thought as to what really needs to be exposed in SharePoint views.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so is it safe to remove them, the fields not in the Library's Columns, from the Property Promotion list in InfoPath?

Comment: Yes, should be safe.

Comment: "Unfortunately, it is very easily possible, because once a form has been published, changes to it's promoted fields will not be pushed to the existing content type in SharePoint" - I don't think this is true I don't work much with IP these days but i remember pushing the updates to existing IP CTs.

Comment: I haven't used IP in a long time either, so maybe it's not true any more, but it was definitely true in SP 2007, and in fact was why I stopped using InfoPath. Also, if it's not true, why would he have promoted fields that aren't in the library? Just curious...

Comment: Because the fields were hidden (Read-Only) and I am idiot for not clicking on the Show Read-Only button this morning. smh

Comment: That'll do it ;)